# PyDAQmx.Task() reises RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nidaqmx, daq-mx

The simple code:

```
from PyDAQmx import Task
task = Task()
```

raises:

```
<...>
File "C:\Users\Adrian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyDAQmx\DAQmxFunctions.py", line 28, in mafunction
    DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo(errBuff,2048)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Error in function:

```
def catch_error_default(f):
    def mafunction(*arg):
        error = f(*arg)
        if error<0:
            errBuff = create_string_buffer(2048)
            DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo(errBuff,2048) # <<<--- error here <<<---
            raise DAQError(error,errBuff.value.decode("utf-8"), f.__name__)
        elif error>0:
            errBuff = create_string_buffer(2048)
            DAQmxGetErrorString (error, errBuff, 2048);
#            print "WARNING  :",error, "  ", errBuff.value.decode("utf-8")
            raise DAQError(error,errBuff.value.decode("utf-8"), f.__name__)
        return error
    return mafunction
```

I have no idea why.

It was after I try to install "instrumental-lib" and "NiceLib" ( http://instrumental-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ni-daqs.html ), but reinstalling Anaconda, PyDAQmx and NIDAQmx Drivers has no effect.

Comment: I exec "DAQmxGetErrorString (error, errBuff, 2048)" and get: b'Internal Software Error occurred in MIG software. Please contact National Instruments Support.'

Comment: After NI MAX >> Tools » Reset Configuration Data.
I have other error: "PyDAQmx.DAQmxFunctions.DAQError: Internal Software Error occurred in MIG software. Please contact National Instruments Support."

Comment: Are you able to open and use a test panel for your device in MAX?

Comment: No. But I find solution of this problem! Anyway thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need clear NI MAX Database:
Open NI MAX -> Tools -> Reset Configuration Data

Then uninstall (not restore) all NI software.

And then install NI DAQmx again.

I also reinstall Anaconda, but i think you don't should to do it.